# Ряд вопросов по пунктуации

Tags: пунктуация

1) Какие символы надо ставить после каждого пункта перечесления: (Нужны ли они вообще?)

**Администрация сервера:** *// 2) Или же тут точку ставить?*

**— Запрещено препятствовать работе администрации сервера;** *// 3) Какое тут, кстати, необходимо ставить тире в начале пункта: **-** или **—**? 4) И вообще, объясните, пожалуйста, в каких случаях употребляется то или иное тире (**-**, **–**, **—**)?*

*// Тут ещё куча пунктов...*

**— Администрация самостоятельно выбирает штрафные санкции для каждого из случаев.** *// 5) Вот, допустим, последний пункт перечесления, после которого ставится точка, да?*

Заранее огромное спасибо! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Корректно:

> Администрация сервера:
>
> — (–) Запрещено препятствовать работе администрации сервера.
>   — (–) Администрация самостоятельно выбирает штрафные санкции для каждого из
>   случаев.

[Вот](http://webstyle.sfu-kras.ru/oformlenie-spiskov) некоторые правила:

> Если элементы списка являются самостоятельными предложениями, то они
>   пишутся с прописной буквы и в конце каждого элемента ставится точка.
>
> В остальных случаях элементы списка начинаются со строчной буквы и
>   завершаются запятой или же точкой с запятой, если элементы достаточно
>   длинны и, тем более, если содержат символы пунктуации.
>
> В конце списка ставится точка.

В принципе, в русском письме среднее (–) и длинное (—) взаимозаменяемы. **"-"** — дефис, а не тире. Он не может быть окружен пробелами, в отличие от тире, сравните: *Он **—** красивый человек* и *Мой дру**г-н**аставник пришел*.

Подробнее об оформлении перечня [здесь](http://delo-press.ru/articles.php?n=5276).

Comment: И ещё, если позволите, один вопрос: *между такими сокращениями, как **т.д.**, **т.п** ставится пробел?* Читал, что между ними необходим неразрывный пробел, но если нет возможности его поставить, то лучше поставить обычный пробел или вообще воздержаться от этого?

Comment: @Никита в идеале -- неразрывный пробел, в жизни чаще всего получается поставить простой, а беспробельное написание, имхо, некорректно. Ну если уж совсем невозможно неразрывные поставить и сокращения не умещаются на строке, думаю, можно и ужасные *т.п. / т.д.* поставить.